# preg_match_all() in php does not show all results

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to match every **opening** and **closing** custom tag `<xyz></xyz>` along with their positions embedded in normal html tags like in these sample:

```
$str =<<<'EOS'
      <xyz id="x464CaqYxUMjG7RJk4yXa8qY" data-arg="x=ktvBDojzvthKO9OOBzQLt6pi">
         <xyz id="x" data-html>
            <h2>Security, Comfort, &amp; Convenience</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dicta magni amet atque doloremque velit unde adipisci omnis hic quaerat.</p>
            <p><xyz id="z9Sjvxxop9BiQKc9HMzuk9Z8"></xyz></p>
         </xyz>
      </xyz>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      <xyz id="ZQpXDHuJHILTVjlRpodO9WrT" data-arg="x=ktvBDojzvthKO9OOBzQLt6pi,y=IyL8raQqbQQM65w7bPWJLRSJ">
         <xyz id="x" data-html>
            <h2>Security, Comfort, &amp; Convenience</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dicta magni amet atque doloremque velit unde adipisci omnis hic quaerat.</p>
            <p><xyz id="z9Sjvxxop9BiQKc9HMzuk9Z8"></xyz></p>
         </xyz>
         <xyz id="IyL8raQqbQQM65w7bPWJLRSJ" data-html>
            <div class="text-center IyL8raQqbQQM65w7bPWJLRSJ">
               <h2>Happy Clients</h2>
               <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. </p>
            </div>
         </xyz>
      </xyz>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
EOS;
```

I'm using this regex in **php**:

```
$tag = "/<xyz([^>]+)>|(<\\/xyz>)/imu";
$out = array();
$result = \preg_match_all($tag, $str, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER | PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

When I print the results with:

```
echo nl2br("\n<pre>".\htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, ENCODING)."</pre>");
echo \nl2br(\print_r($out, true));
echo preg_last_error();
```

I **can** see the sub-pattern `([^>]+)` being printed:

```
[1] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[0] => id="x464CaqYxUMjG7RJk4yXa8qY" data-arg="x=ktvBDojzvthKO9OOBzQLt6pi"
[1] => 10
)
...
```

but **NOT** the 0-indeces that should normally contain the catch ups of all the expression:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[0] => **where is the result???**
[1] => 6
)
...
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

ps: my regex passes in online tools like https://regex101.com/ or http://regexr.com/ with single backslash `<dil([^>]+)>|<\/dil>`

Comment: Following Hassan's answer: echo \nl2br(\htmlspecialchars(\print_r($out, true), ENT_NOQUOTES, ENCODING));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that you are "printing" a HTML results, and your browser automatically parse it.

hitting `CTRL+U` in firefox for example will show you the page source

which is some thing like that:

[image]

as you can see, your data is there,

for example, try to printout your results in textarea as follows:

```
foreach ($out[0] as $_out) {
    echo "<textarea>" . htmlspecialchars($_out[0]) . "</textarea><hr />";
}
```

you will got the results normally.

here is another example: https://3v4l.org/hk7Od

Comment: Oops! Briliant!

Answer (score 0):

Use a far better approach with a parser instead ([**demo**](http://ideone.com/EHP7o6)).
E.g. the following snippet prints out every header (`h2`) under `/xyz/xyz`:

```
<?php
# your string over here

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($your_string_here, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
libxml_clear_errors();

# adjust this xpath as needed
$headers = $xpath->query("//xyz/xyz/h2");
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    echo $header->textContent . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Here, the only thing to adjust is the xpath query.

Comment: the issue is that the browser is parsing the HTML output, not in the pattern it-self.

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll have a deeper look.